# Flink - Run a continuous query on JDBC database using JdbcDynamicTableSource

Tags: postgresql, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am using Flink to read from a postgresql database, which is constantly being updated with new data. Currently, I am able to make one-time queries from this database using Flink's [JdbcCatalog](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/jdbc/catalog/JdbcCatalog.html).

I would like to run a **continuous query** over this database, but because the sql source is not an unbounded input, my query runs once and stops. From what I gather, I could either:

1. Run these queries repeatedly in a brute-force way, perhaps using [Iterations](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/iterations.html).
2. Use [JdbcDynamicTableSource](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/jdbc/table/JdbcDynamicTableSource.html), since continuous queries are meant to be done over dynamic tables.

The second solution would be ideal. However, I have no idea how to use run a continuous query over a JdbcDynamicTableSource. I am able to instantiate a JdbcDynamicTableSource with the required connection options, but how should I run a continuous query over it to produce a dynamic table? Essentially, how do I use JdbcDynamicTableSource?

Any advice/code samples would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 4 ways your problem could get solved:

- 1. Use Changelog Data Capture (CDC) with something like [Debezium](https://debezium.io/). CDC will look at your postgres' WAL an produce a stream of changes. [Some Flink connectors are already available to interpret it](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/formats/debezium.html), and [build a Table from it](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=147427289). This should be your prefered way, but it requires some admin rights to your postgres' instance I believe.
- 2. [Use postgres's LISTEN/NOTIFY](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/07/postgresql-listen-notify/), pipe it to a message queue, interpret it in Flink with some [Deduplication](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/sql.html#deduplication). This techniques seems complicated and brittle, though.
- 3. Use [Kafka Connect's JDBC Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/configuration_options.html), configured for polling your table with `incrementing.column.name` set to an incremented Primary Key, or a last change timestamp that you update with a trigger. You need Kafka Streams though. Not real-time, but you can reduce the poll interval to every second (be sure to have an index on the polled column).

The iceberg here being what happens when there is a failure. I think 1) and 3) should be OK. Also, there are some performance concerns: 1) will slow down your writes to postgres (from the replication I/O overhead), 3) will probably slow down your reads to postgres (from the constant polling)

Also all solutions involve Kafka or a message queue. You could also try 4):

- Implement 3) and poll your database yourself in a Flink SourceFunction. Be sure to use a [Stateful Source Function](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#stateful-source-functions) and have your querying offset as a ValueState, so that in case of failure it can restart at the right offset. Some ideas to deal with duplicate querying: set that source's parallelism to 1, or poll on keys modulo your parallelism.

EDIT: 5. Like Debezium CDC in 1., [but packaged up as source in Flink](https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors). This might be the best option.

Comment: https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors might play a role here too.

Comment: Ah nice :)
Didn't know Debezium was packaged up as a Table Source in Flink. That is such a great news